# Two different front pages?

Tags: 7, redirection

I have a website at mydomain.com. I am creating a clone of it on mydomain2.com. The only difference is that I want the landing pages to be different. Both domains are running the same codebase.

How do I make the landing page differ, depending on what domain you are on?

(Note: Without using i18n)

Comment: They’re using different databases? Just change the front page setting under Site Information in the admin.

Comment: Same database for both.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using the [Domain Access module](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) which is meant for creating a site (with one code base and one database) where certain content is accessible by DomainA and other content is accessible by DomainB. In your case you can set all content to be accessible to both domains and just change the site settings for the front page based on current domain. In D8 there is the [Domain Site Settings](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_site_settings) module which makes this easier, but in D7 you should use [Domain Variable](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_variable) to change site_front based on the current domain.

This method will allow you (for example) to create two view pages or nodes or whatever (one for each domain) and display completely different content (or content in a different order) depending upon the domain.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a custom Route (or hook_menu for D7) that acts as a routing mechanism to send you to the right page. The custom logic would look at the $_SERVER variable and then do a drupal_goto to the appropriate page of choice.

example.com/landing would route to example.com/other-landing

Comment: I dont want two different pages. If it's accessed via either url, it must stay at /

Answer (score -1):

you can use [hook_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7.x) in your template.php file to introduce two different theme to drupal, then in page.tpl.php file check if user is visiting current page (use $is_front variable for that) or you can use page--front.tpl.php, the you can check $front_page value which has the address of front page, based on different address you can print one of your themes

example :
in template.php :

```
function MYTHEME_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'first_front' => array(
      'render element' => 'page',
      'template' => first-front-page,
    ),
    'second_front' => array(
      'render element' => 'page',
      'template' => second-front-page,
    ),
  );
}
```

then in page--front.tpl.php, use this code:

```
<?php if($front_page == "first_url") : ?>
  <?php print render(theme('first_page', array('page' => $page))); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($front_page == "second_url") : ?>
  <?php print render(theme('second_page', array('page' => $page))); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I dont know who downvoted this, but I'll test it and let you know if it works.

Comment: This only allows you to change the look and layout of the front page (per domain)... it does not allow you to have different content. I think that is why it was downvoted

Comment: FYI: Because my new site is only going to have about two pages, this is probably going to be the route I go.